# Using a ultrasound homogenizer to increase meat juicyness

Tags: flavor, food-science, oil, emulsion

I saw a popular TV show where a cook competes against a scientist. They made a pork belly, the cook made a brine and injected the brine directly into the meat with a needle, and the scientist also made a brine solution but used an ultrasonic "stick" (looks like a hand blender) so the brine penetrates the meat deeply.

He called the ultrasonic "stick" a Ultrasonic Homogenizer before and used to emulsify oil and water.

But will the ultrasonic waves help the brine penetrate the protein?

Also, could I theoretically make a "marinade" without oil, but with water using a emulsifying agent like Lecithin or TSP (Trisodium Phosphate, E339) so all the flavours that normally are solved in fat are in the water, and can therefore penetrate the meat far deeper than normal oil based marinades could?

Comment: I don't know anything about 'ultrasonic homoginizers', but there *is* a tool to put liquids into flesh (used for mass vaccinations), but they tend to be more gun-like : https://www.agriland.ie/farming-news/needle-free-injection-gun-revolutionises-pig-vaccinations/

Comment: Ultrasonic Homogenizer devices are not normally used for infusion/brining, instead vacuum/pressure chambers are usually used for that purpose. The homogenizer may create cavitation on the meat that may help with brine absorption, but I do not see much benefit from doing so. It may also turn the meat into paste.

Comment: you have a link to the show you are talking about ?